# Password function won't work

Tags: c, function, crash, passwords

Okay, so I'm trying to make a C program which requires a login and password.
On the first run, it will ask for the user to enter a Login and Password for him, then it will save these info on a global struct, and this global struct will be saved to disk.
The part I'm having trouble with is the password.
I'm trying to make a code so people's passwords won't be visible on the screen. Here is my function for the password:

```
void senha(void)
{
    static int senhac = 0;
    char temps[32];
    do
    {
        temps[senhac] = getchar();
        if(temps[senhac] == EOF)
            return;
        putchar('*');
        conta->senha[senhac] = temps[senhac];
        senhac++;
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(1);
}
```

and the global struct is this one:

```
struct accounts {
    char login[32];
    char senha[32];
    };
struct accounts *conta;
```

When the program reaches the "senha(void)" function, it crashes.
The compiler doesn't show any warnings or errors.
What could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   do
    {
        temps[senhac] = getchar();
        if(temps[senhac] == EOF)
            return;
        putchar('*');
        conta->senha[senhac] = temps[senhac];
        senhac++;
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(1);
```

you are repeating loop more than the size of temps array, `array out of bounds and overflow`.

check condition `while(senhac<32);`

Comment: Your answer saved me from this problem and even one endless loop problem I didn't notice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` returns `int`. Declare `temps[32]` as `int`. If you are not on MS-DOS `fflush(stdin);` will invoke undefined behavior.